# How to change selected text color?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitextview

I'm using UITextView, and I need to change color(or background) of selected text, is it posible and how to implement it?

Thx to all, I've understood  that it was bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at OHAttributedLabel. You will [find it here](https://github.com/AliSoftware/Ali-Cocoa-Classes). It basically allows you to format only parts of a label.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Joseph for mentionning my OHAttributedLabel class/work :)
Hope that helped !

Anyway, since the date of your answer, I did some improvements to my class and fixed some stuff in the code, so don't forget to update / pull from the github repo!

*PS: (Sorry for posting a new answer, can't add a comment to an existing answer yet on SO as I just signed in)*